# Show and hide DIV in UIWebView based on keychain iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, html, uiwebview

How do I hide and show a DIV based on a value from an array?

I've figured out how to edit a DIV in a UIWebView using the following:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)jsWebView
{
    // Replace the <div id="footer"> in a webpage with an <img> instead.
    NSString *jsStuff = [jsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML='<img src=\"http://url.to.image.png\">'"];
}
```

I then have an NSArray that is populated with the Active Directory groups a person is a member of. This array is pulled from the keychain using a library tied to another app and is populated different for each person depending on which group they're in.

So, now I need to figure out how to show and hide a DIV in the UIWebView based on if they're in a particular group or not. I have each DIV labeled with a unique ID, so I'm thinking 'getElementById' will work for identifying which DIV is which. But how do I match them up similar to this:

```
if(NSArray contains thisValue) {
divID.visible =  show;
} else {
divID.visible = hide;
}
```

EDIT: I ended up adding the values from the array to the query string, and used javascript to evaluate and show/hide the different divs based on what it finds in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way, using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method. A basic example would be:

```
if(NSArray contains thisValue) {
   // show
   [jsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').style.display='block'", divID]];
} else {
   // hide
   [jsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').style.display='none'", divID]];
}
```

where divID is NSString with your desired div id.